# Which connector and cables are recommended for CAN?

Tags: military, flight-controls, avionics, aerospace-materials, electronics

Which mechanical connector(s) and cable(s) is/are recommended to arrange a Controller Area Network (CAN) bus communication or its aerospace counterpart ARINC 826 in the aerospace industry (civil & military)?

Comment: Aren't there specs defining the CAN bus and don't they include that information?

Comment: @FreeMan Yes to the former, no to the latter. The connectors are up to the implementer to define according to bus spec. I've seen CAN bus connectors that are everything from simple wire terminals through more complicated multi-function circular connectors.

Comment: @Ron Beyer: Exactly! This where my question pops from.

Comment: Well, silly me, @RonBeyer! I guess I'm much more used to the PC world where standards comprise both physical and electrical specifications. A circular shaped "USB" port is _not_ USB because a round connector is not in the USB spec.

Comment: @FreeMan Not technically, no, but would it surprise you that in the industrial world, I see circular USB ports regularly? Even Ethernet [quite often comes in M12](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/communications/cables_-a-_accessories/ethernet/m12_ethernet_cables), and serial connections are even worse.

Comment: @RonBeyer head asplode...

Comment: D-Sub and Mil Circular are pretty common with the LRUs I work with, but I haven't worked with anything CAN related, just ARINC 429, RS232/422/485

Comment: My avionics courseware shows ethernet is quite common, although having never maintained aircraft with a CAN bus, I don't have an opinion as to whether this is a good idea or not. I'm a 1553  and rs232/422 guy